# Exists firebase-util in Java

Tags: firebase

I found the firebase-util and it is great. 
Does firebase-util exist for Java? Or is possible to use "join" in Java?

I was testing firebase-util and I found that it is a little bit slow. Is it appropriate to join 1:1 rather than 10000 rows with 100 rows (where is better load 10000 a then - if it is needed - join)?

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a version of Fireabse-util for Java. Since this is still an experimental lib, the Firebase team is still soliciting feedback and determining the appropriate API. At some point in the near future, there will also be querying features rolled into the core API, which will be considerably more efficient and complete than this client-side helper lib.

It shouldn't matter if you join 1:1 or 1:many, but 10,000 rows is a very huge number for a join utility on the client. You wouldn't be able to display this many in the DOM at one point anyway as that would be even slower. A better solution would be to create an index and do an intersection against that, only fetching a small subset of the records:

```
// only get the first twenty from path A
var refA = new Firebase('URL/path/A').limit(20);
var refB = new Firebase('URL/path/B');

// intersection only loads if key exists in both paths,
// so we've filtered B by the subset of A
var joinedRef = new Firebase.util.intersection(refA, refB);
```

This would only fetch records in refB that exist in refA, and thus, only the first 10. You can also create an index of specific record ids to fetch, or query for a subset based on priorities, and then use intersection to reduce the payload.